# rosrun map_server map_server couldn't find executable

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following ros-by-example book and in chapter 8, I'm dealing with things in navigation package.

I install the navigation package using 'sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-navigation', it automatically installed "move_base", "map_server", "gmapping" etc packages. After that I can run move_base package using "rosrun move_base move_base" and it shows no error.

But when I input "rosrun map_server map_server", it shows:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named map_server below /opt/ros/indigo/share/map_server
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /opt/ros/indigo/share/map_server
```

By the way, if I attempt to run it in a launch file as follows

```
<launch>
  <!-- Run the map server with a blank map -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find rbx1_nav)/maps/blank_map.yaml"/>

  <include file="$(find rbx1_nav)/launch/fake_move_base.launch" />

  <!-- Run a static transform between /odom and /map -->
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_map_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /odom 100" />

</launch>
```

It shows

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [map_server/map_server]: can't locate node [map_server] in package [map_server]
```

By the way, I can go to the map_server package directory via "roscd map_server", there are a package.xml file and a cmake folder in the directory.

Can anyone help me ?
I'm trying to run the SLAM feature in ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244237/rosrun-map_server-map_server--couldn%27t-find-executable/) by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2016-09-22**:
I assume you meant "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-navigation"?

**Comment by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on 2016-09-24**:
anyone knows？

**Comment by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on 2016-09-24**:
Yes, I mean "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-navigation", I have corrected it, thanks

**Comment by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on 2018-06-27**:
@zinkcious were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To just to be sure that you have map_server installed, can you run `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-map-server` ? (I assume you have `indigo` distro).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-09-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on 2016-09-24**:
I have tried this, it tells me that it already has been installed and no need for updates.

**Comment by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on 2016-09-24**:
Do you have any other suggestions?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-09-25**:
What is the resulting path when you run `roscd map_server` ?

**Comment by [zinkcious](https://answers.ros.org/users/27887/zinkcious/) on 2016-09-26**:
/opt/ros/indigo/share/map_server   I'm still stuck on this problem..

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-09-28**:
Weird. Maybe you had a problem in installation process of ROS. You may try a clean install if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently working under kinetic and can reproduce this behavior very easily as follows:

- If I source my own catkin environment like `source <my_catkin_folder>/devel/setup.bash` and then run `rosrun map_server map_server` it tells me  `Couldn't find executable named map_server`.
- If I source the origin `source /opt/ros/<distro>/setup.bash`, everything works like a charm

**Investigation:**
Turned out I was in copy-paste marathon of packages and so I tainted my own workspace with packages which have the same name.
This confuses `rosrun` as follows: If one investigates [rosrun at line 52](https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/kinetic-devel/tools/rosbash/scripts/rosrun#L52), one will see that it tries to find your desired package via `catkin_find`.
And this command is very fragile when it comes to tainted workspaces.
Unfortunately, the creator decided to pipe the error outputs to `/dev/null` which leaves the user with no clue.

**Solution:** Just investigate the command by hand and see what goes wrong: `catkin_find --without-underlays --libexec --share map_server`.
In my case it gave me:

```
Multiple packages found with the same name "calib":
- teleworkbench/calib
- teleworkbench/map_generator
```

I also made a [PR](https://github.com/ros/ros/pull/182) to solve this once and for all

---

Originally posted by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) with karma: 220 on 2018-06-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2